# Change the return of stored procedure in EF permanently

Tags: c#, visual-studio, stored-procedures, entity-framework-4, edmx

I'm calling stored procedure via entity framework

```
MyObject demande = Demande_analyse_semenceDAO.getContext()
                    .Demande_analyse_By_Id(""+demandeEntry.Id).ToList().FirstOrDefault();
```

By default , the stored procedure return a complex type , and I change it via function import in order to return an Entity

But every time I regenerate  my EDMX I need to  do this work for every stored procedure , is there any way to make it default return type ???

Answer (score 1):

use [dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper) 
you can call stored procedure with T-SQL and have it map the results into List of Object

```
var user = cnn.Query<User>("spGetUser", new {Id = 1},
    commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).SingleOrDefault();
```

The results of be the type of User.

That way, you don't have to do any work when regenerating EDMX file.

Comment: I don't think you need dapper. You can simply use `DbSet.SqlQuery` for entity types.